# Add delay after showMessage()

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentBlock;

    function onSuccessEditUser(result) {
        showMessage(result.Message);
        window.location = '@Url.Action("UserIndex")';
    }
</script>
```

and I would like to add a little delay after showMessage and before window.location.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to fire off the code after a specified interval:

```
function onSuccessEditUser(result) {
    showMessage(result.Message);

    // Wait 1 second
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = '@Url.Action("UserIndex")';
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use java script `setTimeOut` method to execute something after specified time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentBlock;    
function onSuccessEditUser(result) {
showMessage(result.Message);
// Wait 5 second
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("UserIndex")';
},5000);
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `setTimeout(function(){showMessage(result.Message);});` function.
Or opt for jQuery `$(..).delay(300);` http://api.jquery.com/delay/
Whichever you prefer.